# Java FX: FileChooser and file extension

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, filechooser

I'm using Java 7 and I need to know, if it is possible to find out which filter extension was selected... I know that in JavaFX 8.0 we have a proper method, but I must work on lower version. But I have no idea, how to find out which filter is chosen and save file with this extension.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that it is possible in JavaFX 2.2 to identify a selected extension. My research turned up no real solutions when I needed to address the same issue. I ended up settling on a set of file extensions and handling the saving from a custom dialog.